# Loop over everything in a directory?

Tags: shell-script, scripting, terminal, osx

Alright, before this is immediately closed as a duplicate, let me explain. I have attempted many methods such as:

```
for d in /Applications ; do
   echo "$d"
done
```

but that returns

> /Applications

instead of the contents of /Applications.

I also tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=/Applications

for file in $FILES
do
   echo $file
done
```

Which is basically the same thing. I noticed, though, that when I just do:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *
do
    echo $file
done
```

It correctly echoes all of the folders in my home folder. Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: You could also just use `find /Applications -maxdepth 1`.  If you just want directories, use `find /Applications -maxdepth 1 -type d`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. As [noted by Jeff Schaller](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/308297/80216#comment542071_308301), `*` normally works like `ls` —
   it will not show things whose names begin with **`.`** (a period). 
   If you are using bash,
   and you want to get things whose names begin with **`.`**,
   **s**et (turn on) the **sh**ell **opt**ion `dotglob` with the command

   ```
   shopt -s dotglob
   ```

   This will cause `*` to work like `ls -A` — it still won't show **`.`** and **`..`** themselves, but will show everything else beginning with **`.`**.
2. Your question mentions "everything in a directory". 
   This is a somewhat ambiguous phrase. 
   If you mean everything in the (top-level) `/Applications` directory,
   then the other answers are fine. 
   But if you want everything in the `/Applications` *tree*
   (i.e., everything in the `/Applications` directory *and its subdirectories*),
   and you're using bash, set the shell option `globstar` with the command

   ```
   shopt -s globstar
   ```

   This will cause `**` *as a filename component* to mean
   everything here and below.  So

   ```
   for file in /Applications/**
   do
       echo "$file"
   done
   ```

   will list all objects (files, directories, etc.)
   in the `/Applications` *tree*.

   Note that this cannot be combined with other characters
   at the same component level; i.e., you can't do things like `foo**bar`. 
   However, you append other components after the `**`. 
   For example,

   ```
   for file in /Applications/**/README
   ```

   will loop through all files named `README` in the `/Applications` tree,
   and

   ```
   for file in /Applications/**/*.txt
   ```

   will find all files whose names end with `.txt`.
3. You can set multiple options at once; e.g., with

   ```
   shopt -s dotglob globstar
   ```

   See the bash documentation for a complete list of options. 
   You can **u**nset options with `shopt -u`.
4. You should always quote all your shell variable references
   (e.g., `"$file"`) unless you have a good reason not to,
   and you're sure you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 8):

To iterate over the files (and subdirectories) in a directory, you can use

```
for file in /Applications/*
do
    echo "$file"
done
```

Note that if no match is found, the `file` variable will contain the `/Applications/*` string literally (with the asterisk), and this may cause errors if the following commands expect an existing path. If you want to do nothing if no file is matched, you can use the `nullglob` option:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for file in /Applications/*
do
    echo "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 8):

The `*` is called a shell globbing (pathname expansion) operator (`?` and `[]` too), when you call it unquoted, it will expand to all the files in the current directory (without any directory prefix). If you use a prefix e.g. `/foo/*`, it will be expanded to all files in directory `/foo`.

Note that, it is used to match certain files too, for example to match only the files that start with `foo` and ends in `bar` in the current directory, use the glob pattern:

```
foo*bar
```

So, the `for` loop can now takes the form:

```
for f in foo*bar; do echo "$f"; done
```

Read the `man` page of your shell to get more idea on shell globbing.

Comment: :0 I'll choose the one that served me best

Comment: @Jack be aware that the `*` wildcard doesn't differentiate files, folders, or any other entity that can be found in a directory. So if you have a directory inside your `/Applications` it will also get matched by `/Applications/*`

Comment: And, depending on the dotglob setting, will or will not pick up "hidden" files

Answer (score -4):

This format allows you to choose from all the listing and sorting options of 'ls':

```
ls -at $DIR | while read i; do echo $i; done
```

Comment: Using `$DIR` without `"`s sourrouding it is bad. And the need to parse the `ls` output puts unnecessary restrictions as well.

Comment: Using `$i` without quoting it is bad, too.